# Android Maps with Pins from a PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, android

I have been looking into tutorials on how to make a android map that will display markers from a server and the users location. All the tutorials seems outdated. Can someone help me?

Comment: You can use Api i guess the will give you longitude and latitude and then you can  display the location in android using google map by just giving longitude and latitude

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i will try your method.